# jQuery - Enable Textbox based on Checkboxes - Dynamically Generated

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

All,

I am trying to dynamically generate a list of checkboxes and textboxes associated with each other.

On the client side I want to dynamically enable the text boxes when the corresponding checkbox is selected.

C# code to generate the checkboxes and text boxes

```
foreach (DataRow row in AccountsDS.Tables["Table"].Rows)
{
  CheckBox c1 = new CheckBox();
  c1.ID = "chk" + row["Num"];
  c1.Text = row["Num"].ToString();
  c1.CssClass = "AccountSelectBox";
  c1.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;

  TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
  t1.ID = "txt" + row["Num"];
  t1.CssClass = "AccountAmountBox";
  t1.Enabled = false;
  t1.Width = new Unit("50px");
  t1.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;

  TableRow tr = new TableRow();
  TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
  TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
  TableCell tc3 = new TableCell();
  TableCell tc4 = new TableCell();
  TableCell tc5 = new TableCell();


  tc1.Controls.Add(c1);
  tc2.Controls.Add(t1);
  tc3.Text = row["Num"].ToString();
  tc4.Text = row["Num1"].ToString();
  tc5.Text = row["Num2"].ToString();

  tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
  tr.Cells.Add(tc3);
  tr.Cells.Add(tc4);
  tr.Cells.Add(tc5);
  tr.Cells.Add(tc2);

  AccountsTable.Rows.Add(tr);
}
```

Client Side script to enable textboxes

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $(".AccountSelectBox").change(function () {
                var index = 0;
                $(".AccountSelectBox").each(function () {
                    alert($(this).attr('checked'));
                });
            });
        });
```

The checked always gives me "false". Is this the right way to do it? I am trying to look for all the checked fields and use their ID to enable textboxes with the same ID. (both have different prefix making them unique)

Is there a better (or simpler) way to do this?

**EDIT:**

using $(this).attr('id') also gives me 'undefined'. And trying $(this).val gives a long text of HTML which seems completely irrelevant.

Dynamically Generated HTML

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_AccountsTable" style="width:100%;margin-top:20px; text-align:center;">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="AccountSelectBox"><input id="chk7617537" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chk7617537" /><label for="chk7617537">7617537</label></span></td><td>7617537</td><td>03/22/2014</td><td></td><td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt7617537" type="text" id="txt7617537" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled AccountAmountBox" style="width:50px;" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="AccountSelectBox"><input id="chk7685249" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chk7685249" /><label for="chk7685249">7685249</label></span></td><td>7685249</td><td>04/23/2014</td><td></td><td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt7685249" type="text" id="txt7685249" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled AccountAmountBox" style="width:50px;" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="AccountSelectBox"><input id="chk27979714" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chk27979714" /><label for="chk27979714">27979714</label></span></td><td>27979714</td><td>04/18/2014</td><td></td><td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt27979714" type="text" id="txt27979714" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled AccountAmountBox" style="width:50px;" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="AccountSelectBox"><input id="chk7701997" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chk7701997" /><label for="chk7701997">7701997</label></span></td><td>7701997</td><td>05/07/2014</td><td></td><td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt7701997" type="text" id="txt7701997" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled AccountAmountBox" style="width:50px;" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="AccountSelectBox"><input id="chk28183452" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chk28183452" /><label for="chk28183452">28183452</label></span></td><td>28183452</td><td>05/07/2014</td><td></td><td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt28183452" type="text" id="txt28183452" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled AccountAmountBox" style="width:50px;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is what I get when I use `$(this).val`

[image]

EDIT Reading from textbox

Tried

```
$(".AccountAmountBox :input").blur(function () {
                alert($(this).text);
            });

$(".AccountAmountBox").blur(function () {
                alert($(this).val);
            });
```

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: The HTML is just a simple empty ASP Table 

<asp:Table ID="AccountsTable" runat="server" style="margin-top:20px; text-align:center;" >

        </asp:Table>

Comment: i mean generated html after adding dynamic html elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AccountSelectBox** is  the class of span you need to write this selector:

```
$(".AccountSelectBox input:checkbox").change(function () {
                alert(this.checked);
            });
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
//enable/disable textbox of row on checkbox checked and unchecked

$(".AccountSelectBox input:checkbox").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) 
       $(this).closest("tr").find('.AccountAmountBox').removeAttr("disabled");
    else 
       $(this).closest("tr").find('.AccountAmountBox').prop("disabled", true);

});

//reads value when user leaves textbox

$('.AccountAmountBox').blur(function () {

    alert($(this).val())

})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/gUYWd/)

Comment: Thanks, That worked. Just out of curiosity, are checkboxes like this always rendered in a span ?

Comment: the webform render engine do this what i see

Comment: I want to get the text of the text box but it again doesnt seem to work. Can you please look at the edit and help ?

Comment: you want corresponding textbox text when it is checked?

Comment: once its checked, I enable it. Then they enter something inside it and I try to read when they leave it

Comment: I was missing the paranthesis () with val. Thanks for your help

Comment: you should refer for documentation to jquery website before using any method

Comment: my bad. I was too pre-occupied with making this work. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The *current* checkbox state is returned by:

```
var currentlyChecked = $( elem ).prop( "checked" )
```

The *initial* checkbox state (which never changes) is returned by:

```
var initiallyChecked = ($( elem ).attr( "checked" ) == "checked")
```

For more information check [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).  Of special interest:

> According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute has no value or is set to empty string value or even "false". This is true of all boolean attributes.
>
> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property:
>
> ```
> if ( elem.checked )
>
> if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )
>
> if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )
> ```

Comment: I updated my jQuery to alert($(this).prop('checked')); but it still gives me undefined. I also tried is(':checked') still false

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but using $(this).attr('id') also gives me 'undefined'. And trying $(this).val gives a long text of HTML which seems completely irrelevant.